# Is this a reasonably secure way to use $_GET

Tags: php, security, get

I am just a weekend coder and only work on my own projects but I would like to use $_GET in a reasonably secure way. I typically use $_GET from a table with many items that I would like to perform some action on (Edit, Delete). Do any of you veterans see any security issues with the functions I have created or a simpler more elegant way of doing it? I appreciate any input, Thanks.

```
<?php session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['SecretKey'])) {
    $_SESSION['SecretKey'] = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
}

function GetURLEncode($ArrayData,$SecretKey,$Echo = true) {
    $GetQuery = http_build_query($ArrayData,'','&');
    $Checksum = http_build_query(Array("Checksum" => hash_hmac('ripemd160', $GetQuery, $SecretKey)));
    if ($Echo) {
        echo '<a href="?'.$GetQuery.'&'.$Checksum.'">'.htmlspecialchars($ArrayData['Action']).'</a>';
    } else {
        return "?".$GetQuery."&".$Checksum;
    }
}

function GetURLDecode($GetData,$SecretKey,&$ReturnData) {
    $Checksum = $GetData['Checksum'];
    unset($GetData['Checksum']);
    $GetQuery = http_build_query($GetData,'','&');
    if (hash_equals(hash_hmac('ripemd160', $GetQuery, $SecretKey),$Checksum)) {
        $ReturnData = $GetData;
        return true;
    }
    $ReturnData = "";
    return false;
}

if (!empty($_GET)) {
    if (GetURLDecode($_GET,$_SESSION['SecretKey'],$ReturnData)) {
        echo "Array Returned<br>";
        echo var_dump($ReturnData)."<br><Br>";
    } else {
        echo "Checksum Error<br><br>";
    }
}

//Example 1
$MyArray1 = Array ("FirstName" => "John",
                   "LastName" => "Doe",
                   "Adderss" => "12345 MyStreet",
                   "City" => "Apple Valley",
                   "State" => "California");

echo "Sample 1<br>";
$URL = GetURLEncode($MyArray1,$_SESSION['SecretKey'],false);
echo '<a href="'.$URL.'">Click Me</a>';

//Example 2
$MyArray2 = Array(Array("Id" => 0,"Make" => "Chevy","Model" => "HHR"),
                  Array("Id" => 1,"Make" => "Chevy","Model" => "Corvette"),
                  Array("Id" => 2,"Make" => "Ford","Model" => "Mustang"),
                  Array("Id" => 3,"Make" => "Nissan","Model" => "Sentra"),
                  Array("Id" => 4,"Make" => "Ford","Model" => "Ranger"),
                  Array("Id" => 5,"Make" => "Dodge","Model" => "Charger"));?>
<br><br>
<table>
    <th>sample 2</th>
<?php foreach ($MyArray2 as $Array) { ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?= $Array['Make'];?></td>
        <td><?= $Array['Model'];?></td>
        <td><?php GetURLEncode(array("Id"=>$Array['Id'],"Action"=>"Edit"),$_SESSION['SecretKey']);?></td>
        <td><?php GetURLEncode(array("Id"=>$Array['Id'],"Action"=>"Delete"),$_SESSION['SecretKey']);?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>

</table>
```

Comment: What are you trying to protect? Instead of this you should use HTTP methods, i.e POST (Create), GET (Retrieve), PUT (Update), DELETE, then a CSRF in a GET param can only GET, combine that with secure SQL queries etc and there is no use in encoding a token in the url, also dont use md5 use somthing like hash_hmac, its for signing data.

Comment: if a user has to log in to delete\edit, then  just check that. If you are trying to protect guessed id's just add a random hash to the array (could replace the 'Id' altogether), it has no need for being user unique here.

Comment: Just trying to protect against a user tampering with the URL. I'm looking into POST (Create), GET (Retrieve), PUT (Update), and hash_hmac. thanks for the information.

Comment: In addition to using HMAC, also consider that you should be escaping all data correctly in the URL.  (Use `http_build_query()` for the whole thing!  Use a canonical version of your data, not just hashing the query string itself or parameter order won't be able to be changed.)  Also use `htmlspecialchars()` around any arbitrary data (your URLs) injected into HTML so that things are escaped properly.

Answer (score -1):

Hello there weekend coder, the only issue i see with using a GET method is that a user can directly change the GET data in the url. for example, lets take youtube for example ( at least back in the day ), each youtube video has a GET value of `v` and it's value is some random 64bit alphanumeric hex hash of digits and you can see it directly in the URL `youtube com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxxxxx` since this is so, you can manually change this value and it will take you to another video because you changed the `video id number`. this is useful because you can copy this link and send it to your friends.

on the other hand, POST is different as you cannot really directly change the POST data values being sent. though there some mischievous ways some may be able too, which is why form validation is always needed for POST forms and values!!!

if we changed youtube's methods to use POST, all youtube videos would have youtubeDOTcom as the URL and the video ID would be hidden underneath the page as POST. now the user cannot directly see their video's random unique ID and cannot send the link to others to be shared.

Hope this explains a bit, it depends on what type of information you are sending. if you think it should be secured and not visible to all users, use POST. if you want the link to be shared and changed often to view different pages,media, etc, that's not confidential, you can use GET

Comment: `some mischievous ways some`  Its quite easy to use a browser plugin for testing API's such as RestClient, or any of a dozen such plugins to change post.  I use the same plugin to test API that I make in non mischievous ways.

Comment: yes sir exactly. even editing the HTML code directly and adding a new form and input tag with correct name values and redirect page names.

Comment: Your on the mark about what Verbage (they are HTTP verbs) one should use, I hate when people make search pages and use POST it just drives me crazy ... lol

Comment: wouldn't hashing the $_GET data with a secret key and performing a checksum prevent tampering of the URL? Thanks for the response.

Comment: No for one Hashing is one way, even if it was 2 way, the key would be needed by both client and server, and if you used asymmetric encryption (public private key), it would be hard to implement that in Javascript.  And the public key would be easy to acquire, so one could simple fake a message.

Comment: I understand that hashing is one way. The links are generated from the server and hashed with a secret key generated for the session and stored in a session key. on the receiving page it takes the secret key from the session and hashes it with the data in the URL and then compares the hashes.